# Best way to compare editions of a running race?

Tags: r, mean

What is the best way to compare performances between editions of the same running event? In this case, distance and elevation varies slightly from year to year.

1. Compare differences between editions for all runners who participated in both? But then age is a factor that may needs to be considered (such as the World Masters Athletics Age Factors).
2. Compare mean of top n runners each year? Which may or may not reflect all runners.
3. ?

There is a cutoff time too, so in case of #1 above, I'd need to remove runners within x minutes of the cutoff in the first year, as they can't get slower time in the second year without missing cutoff.

Which would be the most fair way to compare edititions, in order to be able to rank performances across editions?

Comment: "There is a cutoff time too, so in case of #1 above, I'd need to remove runners within x minutes of the cutoff in the first year,..." I'm visualizing a plane hull full of bullet holes. There are methods to account for censoring, i.e. an event time that is past the observation threshold.

Comment: are you actually able to link runner IDs between the two races, so you know who exactly ran in both races?

Comment: Yes, the races are in a database with runners linked to profiles. So it is indeed possible to see all races run by a runner.

Comment: About censoring (or truncation?), if I compare runners who finished both races it sounds like a good option to exclude those who could only improve in the second race (as the others who may have started missed the cutoff if they were slower the second time)?